# COM Call not returning, but possibly crashing?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have an app that is using COM to talk to another 3rd party application. Most of the time everything works great.

But once in a while the following call to `OpenPage()` gets some strange behavior. When this happens, the function just breaks. The thread continues, but neither one of the message boxes show up. Nothing is "thrown". And there are no indications that anything is wrong on my side.

The thread continues to run, except from here on out, the `CComPtr` can never return anymore, but doesn't get hung waiting for the return from the 3rd party.
I know the thread continues because the user can continue to use my app and it calls the various functions associated and is traced.

My question is 2-fold. Why would this be happening? Is it mainly due to something in the third party application?

How can I add some code to diagnose this?

`m_spThirtParty` is a `CComPtr`.

```
LRESULT Open()
{
    HRESULT hr;

    try 
    {
        hr = m_spThirdParty->OpenPage(&pObj->m_orderNumber);    
        Trace(hr);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        Error();
        MessageBox(NULL, "Fail", "Fail", MB_OK);
    }

    if(FAILED(hr))
    {
        MessageBox(NULL, "Returned Fail", MB_OK);
        return 0;
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, "Success", "Success", MB_OK);
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in Advance!

---

WhozCraig: Sorry I left some code out. I do check the hr in the try block. But it never gets to that point. When the issue happens, it exits out of the function. –  Eric C 12 mins ago

MSalters: That is the issue. I'm not privy to what is happening once I call OpenPage. All I know is after I call it, I get this weird behaviour –  Eric C 11 mins ago

thang: Sorry I left out some code to try to be concise. I do check the return of hr and log it in that try block, but it always skips that and exits out of the function with no other actions being taken

Comment: do you know if openpage ever returns?  why don't you output a debug message right after

Comment: I don't see how you can claim "Success" after that try-catch when you never bothered to check the returned HRESULT.

Comment: "The thread continues". Well, no, it doesn't. If it did, it would run the second message box call (and possibly the first). Also, what does it even mean when you say "the CComPtr can never return" ? Pointers do not return, functions do.

Comment: Operator->() of CComPtr can't throw and throwing c++ exceptions across a com interface call is not allowed so your try/catch is not useful.  You are also not checking the return result `hr`.

Comment: I've amended the code. Even though I try to trace the hr return value, it skips that line and all subsequent lines. It then goes into the next function

Comment: Try changing the catch-block to `MessageBox(...); return Error();` and see what happens. Also: Are you able to step through the code? Try reproducing the error by using different hardcoded values to pass to `OpenPage`.

Comment: Investigate whether `OpenPage` might be throwing a SEH exception. Also it'd be useful to know where the server is (in-proc, OOP on same PC, or on a different PC)